One number grid, two ways to divide it
Find a rectangular grid of the smallest area that satisfies the following:

Each cell contains an integer between 1 and 3 inclusive.
The grid follows the Fillomino rule:

When the cells are divided into connected groups containing same numbers, each number belongs to a group of that many cells.


The grid follows the Sudoku-like rule:

It is possible to divide the cells into connected groups of 3 cells each, so that each group contains a 1, a 2, and a 3.




Optional bonus: Can you find such a grid using numbers from 1 to 4 inclusive? Posted as a separate puzzle.

The bonus may be worthy of it's own question.

@DanielMathias Done.

Another bonus question: find a grid that contradicts 'the Sudoku-like' rule.

It might also be interesting to find the smallest tillable segment that follows this rule when tessellated

Solution:

 

Proof it's the smallest:

 Twos come in groups of 2 and threes come in groups of 3. The final grid must have an equal number of twos and threes. Hence, we need at least $6=LCM(2,3)$ twos and threes. So we need at least $18=6 \times 3$ numbers in the grid. That minimum is achieved with our solution.


When I posted the puzzle, I had a solution whose lower half is different from Jujustum's:



